# setInterval with very low timespan

Tags: jquery

I am building a calculator with Jquery mobile.

Some things are calculated by slider values or html values like this:

```
function refresh(){ 
        $("#leistung").html(($('#slider-vertical2').val()*1.2/3600*$('#slider-vertical3').val()).toFixed(0));
        $("#nutzenergie").html(toLocalFormat($('#slider-vertical').val()*$("#leistung").html()));
        $("#kostenersparnis").html(toLocalFormat($('#slider-vertical2').val()*1.2/3600*$('#slider-vertical3').val()*$('#slider-vertical').val()*0.9*1.1*$('#slider-vertical4').val()/100/0.9));
        $("#co2emission").html(toLocalFormat($("#leistung").html()*$('#slider-vertical').val()*0.00055/0.9, true));
        $("#amortisationszeit").html(toLocalFormat($('#slider-vertical5').val()/$('#kostenersparnis').html()/1000,true));
    }
```

Now I would need to update the values frequently.

I first used

```
$(document).on("vmousemove taphold tap swipe")
```

But unfortunately that does not include click-pressing the +/- buttons in the calculator.
I could probably set an interval for the event of the mousebutton being down, but instead I chose the easy way out like this:

```
setInterval(function(){refresh();},10);
```

It does what I want and works fine on this CPU, but I am unsure wether it could generate issues with slower (touch) devices. Since it fires a few calculations every 10ms.

There is probably a better way to do what I am trying to do.

Comment: That does seem like a really bad idea, especially since those sliders probably have events for whenever they change ?

Comment: Well, the cpu stays comfortably at 0% the whole time and goes up to 10% when sliding.